# Is there any proper documentation with examples available for the QAF?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, documentation, qaf

I want to commend QAF team for developing an excellent framework, especially for its robust reporting features. However, I noticed that there is a lack of documentation and sample projects illustrating the usage of various methods.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples of method calls on the website. For instance, I'm interested in implementing the "move to element" functionality, but I'm unsure whether I should use an existing function within the framework or if I should follow a default approach.

**I kindly request if there is any documentation or reference material available that could help clarify the usage of these methods.**

I attempted to navigate the website and review the Stack Overflow discussions. I also inspected the contents of the jar files, but regrettably, I couldn't attain a comprehensive grasp of the framework's functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are few useful resources:

- [QAF documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/)
- [QAF web services support documentation](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki)
- [PERFECTO QUANTUM](https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/courses/quantum.htm)

Regarding implementing custom functionality it's completely project specific and need programing as well as respective library knowledge (for instance selenium, appium). There are 10+ [qaf-support libraries](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf#support-libraries) also available. You can refer documentation of respective libraries.

For

- [selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation)
- [appium documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/latest/)
- [testng](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

All together should help you to achieve your goal. For instance, in order to create reusable function for move to element, one can refer

- [selenium actions](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/#move-to-element)
- [creating custom step](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/Describe_Test_Step.html)
- [existing step implementations](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/CommonStep.java)